# “C# get private set” Translation for public DebugWriter Writer

Tags: c#

This line of code works in C# 6.0, but doesn't work in earlier versions:

```
//valid syntax in C# 6.0

    public DebugWriter Writer { get; private set; } = new DebugWriter();
```

My question is what this is the abbreviation for? How do I convert it to code that works in earlier versions?

From what I understand:

```
public DebugWriter Writer { get; private set; }
```

---------------stands for---------------

```
private object writer;
public object Writer{
get{ return writer;}
}
```

But I don't know how to translate the "= new DebugWriter();" part...

Comment: You do mean __C# 6__ , not _.net 6_ , right?

Comment: That "doesn't work" is about the `=<startvalue>` part. The rest is an auto-implemented property that existed some versions before 6

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea how to convert this into a code that works before 6? And I mean C#

Comment: Simply move the assignment to the constructor(s).

Comment: If the question does not reopen, it stands for `private object writer = new DebugWriter();
public object Writer{
get{ return writer;} private set { writer = value;}
}`

Comment: Except the type is not `object` but `DebugWriter`

Comment: Thanks, that's it, even though I get other error messages now, but at least I can make sense of them :D

Answer (score 2):

The *C# 6* feature you are asking about is called `auto property initializer`.

This is how we could rewrite the code only with syntax that is included in *C# 2*:

```cs
private DebugWriter writer = new DebugWriter();

public DebugWriter Writer
{
    get
    {
        return writer;
    }
    private set
    {
        writer = value;
    }
}
```

(The feature `access modifiers on properties` is not available in *C# 1*.)

If you'd like to "lower" code yourself, I can wholeheartedly endorse [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy), or the great [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/).